# How to get the get(...) index manually

Tags: java, android, singleton

I have the following problem. I think it's, at least, interesting. And I would like to find a solution too :)

I have an internal array of users that, for some reasons, is storing the images of each user in a `singleton class`. This singleton class is storing correctly each `ArrayList` of images for each user.

When I go to the part in which I want to access each user image list, I should do something like this:

```
myUsersList.get(userPosition).getImages();
```

But, as the class where I store my image list is a singleton class, it needs to know the index of the image list to be returned. In another case, it won't know which of the image list to return.

My image list is a:

```
List<List<Bitmap>>
```

Until now all my efforts have failed. I would like to know if there's a way to pass this index to my singleton class in some way, so my image list access looks like the code above.

Any idea?

**EDIT:**
I try to explain myself better:

I have a class that contains some user information. Due to some memory management of my application, I have to store my users' image list in a singleton class in order to be accessed externaly.

In order to make things easier on the data access layer, I'm trying to make this singleton image list transparent. So, when I have a user with all it's information on an regular ArrayList, I try to access it like this:

```
myUsersArrayList.get(userPosition);
```

As my user images are on a singleton class, externaly I have to access the user's image list like this:

```
mySingletonClassImages.get(userPosition);
```

or I can implement something like this:

```
myUsersArrayList.get(userPosition).getImages(userPosition);
```

But I want it to look like this:

```
myUsersArrayList.get(userPosition).getImages();
```

So I have problems how to get the index without passing it.

I don't know if now it's clearer...

Comment: Iterate through the outer list until you find the user you want or consider storing the outer list as a `HashMap`, with the keys being the `userPosition`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick is to have `myUsersList.get(userPosition)` return something that:

- encapsulates the value of `userPosition`
- has a method `getImages()` that will use the encapsulated value.

So:

```
class Special {
  private int userPosition;
  private List<List<Bitmap>> images;
  public Special(int up,List<List<Bitmap>> i) { userPosition = up; images = i }
  public List<Bitmap> getImages() { return ...; }
}
```

now make `myUsersList.get(userPosition)` returns an instance of the previous class.

```
class UsersList {
  public Special get(int up) {
    return new Special(up,theSingleton);
  }
}
```

Comment: But in order to access the specific image list, I have to do it in two steps, in other case, the index won't be known, isn't it?
Something like: user = myUsersList.get(userPosition); 
Next line: user.getImages();

Comment: No `myUsersList.get(userPosition).getImages()` will call the method `getImages()` of the `Special` instance.

Comment: Not clear... with that I loose my userList.get(i). I want to keep both `userList.get(position)` and `userList.get(position).getImages()`.

Comment: @Sonhja What is your definition of losing?

Comment: If the name `Special` is unclear, then call it `User` and add to it anything you want.